# How to white pad/border an image with magickwand?

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, magickwand

I have an image that is 180x240 and I want to pad/border it with white until it fits the size 360x240, so the original content from image won't get distort.

http://www.magickwand.org/ - I can't find any suggestive function in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Magickwand but with Imagemagick there is an operator called extent which does what you want. But I can not see any mention of extent in the documentation you linked.

You may have to create a white canvas of 360x240 and composite your image onto it.

Alternativly could you use MagickBorderImage and have the border set to 0 or 1 on the height and 90 on the width?

Comment: This MagickBorderImage came from your link so assume it is in the MagickWand library and the composite you should be able to do from the library as well.